# Dinamic parsing variables to array_map

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections, eval

I have this function

```
    public function saveVariantValue($id, $data, $langs, $field, $client)
    {
        $transformation = [];
        $parts1 = explode(';', $data[$field][1]);
        $parts2 = explode(';', $data[$field][2]);

        $tmp_arr = array_map(null, $parts1, $parts2);
        $transformation[] = array_map(
            function($v) { return array_combine(["1","2"], $v); }, 
            $tmp_arr
        );
        //here i use the transformation array//
    }
```

the function transform an input array from this,

```
[
  {
      "1": "tag_es1;tag_es2;tag_es3",
      "2": "tag_en1;tag_en2;tag_en3"
  }
]
```

to this

```
[
  {
    {
      "1" : "tag_es1",
      "2" : "tag_en1"
    },
    {
      "1" : "tag_es2",
      "2" : "tag_en2"
    },
    {
      "1" : "tag_es3",
      "2" : "tag_en3"
    }
  }
]
```

each `1` and `2` represent a language id from the database, if you check the code, it will only work if i send both languages, but in some cases based on the users permission, the user will be able to send

```
[
  {
      "1": "tag_es1;tag_es2;tag_es3"
  }
]
```

i want to make the code mode dynamically so instead of declaring `parts1` and `parts2` i could create a string of values and then eval the string like this

```
$str  = '';
$eval = '';
foreach($langs as $l) {
    //i create the string "variables", the values of the "parts" must be an array, that's why the explode
    $str  .= 'parts'.$l->id.'='.serialize(explode(";", $variant[$l->id])).';&';
    //i need to pass the "parts" to array_map so i create a string to pass it as the function parameters;
    $eval .= '$parts'.$l->id.', ';
}
$str  = rtrim($str, '&');
$eval = rtrim($eval, ', ');
parse_str($str);
//if i var_dump $parts1 or $parts2 i get the correct values
$tmp_arr = array_map(null, eval($eval));//here i fail
```

so far when i call array_map it fails throwing `syntax error, unexpected end of file`

so here goes the question, how can i make this code work? and it is ok to do this? is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Why not check if there's only one element in array? If two - do `array_map`, else - do something else.

Comment: the language quantity could vary in time, it could have 3, 4 or n number of languages, so that would'nt be very maintenable

Comment: What wouldn't be efficient? If one key - do one thing, if more than one - do `array_map`.

Comment: doing `$parts1 = explode(';', $data[$field][1]); $parts2 = explode(';', $data[$field][2]); $parts3 = explode(';', $data[$field][3]); ... $partsN = explode(';', $data[$field][n]); ` and then `$tmp_arr = array_map(null, $parts1, $parts2, $parts3, ... $partsN);` is what i dont want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about [variadic arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) and use this:

```
$a = '1,2,3';
$b = '4,5,6';
$c = '7,8,9';
$r = [1 => $a, 2 => $b, 3 => $c];

$parts = array_map(function($v) { return explode(',', $v); }, $r);

print_r(array_map(null, ...$parts));
```